# How To Kill Background Process on C#

Tags: c#, process, rdp

I want to build my own Rdp programs with c#. That's why i made a login page screen and i took the login input from user. After that in order to start rdp process i used this code.

```
 Process rdcProcess = new Process();
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/generic:TERMSRV/{ipaddressbox.Text} /user: {usernamebox.Text} /pass: {passwordbox.Text}";

        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/v {ipaddressbox.Text}"; // ip or name of computer to connect
        rdcProcess.Start();
```

When I log in using my user information, a form opens and the rdp program works without any problems. However, when I close that form screen, the remote desktop connection does not end, it continues to work in the background. My request is that when I close the form, the remote desktop connection is disconnected and kill the rdp process. How can I achieve this?

Comment: To kill a process you can use `Process.GetProcessesByName("rdp...").FirstOrDefault().Kill();`
I'm not sure if its possible to disconnect RDP gracefully.

Comment: You're right but i want to do it programmatically, i mean process kill should happen when the form is closed

Comment: `tsdiscon sessionid`, and `LOGOFF sessionid` seem to work. See: https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/disconnecting-sessions.html

Comment: i will try it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. When I closed the rdp screen, the mstsc process was dying. I wrote an if block that checks for this and exited the program if the mststc process was not running.

```
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc.exe");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname process name should be a friendly name so in this case, you always end up with pname.Length == 0 because "mstsc.exe" is not a friendly name to the mstsc process